# Mongo connector is not importing all fields from MongoDB collections just id field is imported

Tags: python, mongodb, solr, mongo-collection

I have created database and collections into mongoDB using pymongo and
I want to import documents from MongoDB to solr for creating search
engine from my application. I have used mongo connector for importing
document and documents are imported but only id field is showing when
I fire search query.

I have defined and checked  schema like million times,it's perfectly fine I am just not able to figure  out what is the problem because id of
documents which are imported are as same as mongodb documents which shows documents gets imported correctly but why other fields of document are not showing?

document in solr:look at the id field which is same as mongodb document [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufPI0.png)

I have defined schema of the collection [as follows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7Ymz.png)

Please help me I have searched entire Internet but could not find what the problem really is.

This is also my final year project and I have just learned solr and don't know much about it and I am short of time too, so any help will be life-saving.

Comment: So what does your schema look like? How are you indexing the data?

Comment: see the 2 nd screen shot for schema

Comment: There is no second image that shows the active schema for the collection, the second image shows your query result.

Comment: sorry my bad! I have corrected it!Now see!

Comment: Hi Agrawal Ankush; can I comment on your question - it would be much better if you could copy and paste your data, your query and your results _into_ the question, instead of linking to screenshots? It is easier to read and understand, both for a regular user and for indexers / screen readers / etc.